# Why is there a module for version 9 of core?

Tags: community-official-site

I checked this [module page](https://drupal.org/project/bad_judgement), it have the download option for Drupal 9 version. Why is Drupal 9 is launched when there isn't an official stable Drupal 8 release? Is there anything wrong with Drupal 8?

Why did they ignore Drupal 8? I also found the [Drupal 9 development snapshot release.](https://drupal.org/node/1859548)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well the "Bad Judgment" module you linked to claims:

> This module provides an explicit dependency for modules whose usage requires bad judgement. Joke modules often require "bad judgement".

So I wouldn't take that version number too seriously.

From the core download page you linked to:

> Placeholder for the Drupal 9.x release. Not intended for actual use by anyone except the issue queue version selector.

It's just a placeholder for the next version (forward-thinking and all that). It doesn't mean there's anything wrong with Drupal 8, and it doesn't mean Drupal 9 will be out any time soon.

Comment: A tiny thing I want to add is that the 9.x branch was created in the issue queue when the feature freeze for D8 approached. There has to be somewhere to put those issues/features that get rejected from D8. :)